# Input in Manipulate

Tags: notebooks, cdfplayer

```
Plot[Evaluate[
    Input["Please input a function of x to plot with one parameter \
        \[Alpha] to manipulate"]], {x, 0, 1}]
```

This work without doubt. But this not

```
Manipulate[
    Plot[Evaluate[
        Input["Please input a function of x to plot with one parameter \
          \[Alpha] to manipulate"]], {x, 0, 1}], {\[Alpha], 0, 1}]
```

1) Is there a way to make it work.
2) I have no experience of cdf. But, if ever there is a way to make it work could it works in cdf ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no reason to keep your `Input` inside of `Manipulate`, you don't want a dialog show up every time it updates, right? Probably you need something like this:

```
ClearAll[f, x, \[Alpha]]
f[x_, \[Alpha]_] = 
  Input["Please input a function of x to plot with one parameter \
\[Alpha] to manipulate"];
Manipulate[Plot[f[x, \[Alpha]], {x, 0, 1}], {\[Alpha], 0, 1}]
```

You can also take advantage of built-in math expression interpreter and enter functions in a more familiar way, like "sin(alpha pi / x)" for example:

```
f[x_, \[Alpha]_] = 
 Interpreter["MathExpression"][
  InputString[
   "Please input a function of x to plot with one parameter \[Alpha] \
to manipulate"]]
```